# Company name before website URL

Tags: url, web, certificate, mozilla

I was downloading addon from sudomain of Mozilla websites & I found very nice thing over there. Before the full URL, they have put the company/foundation name, which is "Mozilla Foundation (US)". You can see this at https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/.

I tried searching on the web about this but didn't get any idea, how it can be done. May be some certification for the website but what can be that ?

Comment: Just click on it, and you can see what it is.

Comment: Yeah it says "Verfied by digicert"

Comment: I added some info below.

Answer (score 2):

This is what the [green certificate info](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-tell-if-my-connection-is-secure) means in Firefox

A green padlock indicates:

```
The website's address has been verified using an Extended Validation (EV) certificate.
The connection between Firefox and the website is encrypted to prevent eavesdropping.
```

Answer (score 1):

That is their SSL certificate if i  am not wrong. You can check this site out for details     http://www.digicert.com/

You need to buy one.

Comment: Are you sure we can do this by taking SSL certificate? Are there various kind of SSL certificate, I mean specially for this one. As so many websites have SSL certificate but never see this things..

Comment: Yeah, there are many sites which have the green thing.  Read this http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37367/chrome-does-not-show-green-bar-with-ev-ssl-but-firefox-and-ie-does

Comment: Yeah right, there are posts about this. Thanks for linking :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes Rajeev, It's called as 'Digital Certificate'.

You need to purchase the digital certificates from any web hosting company with your registered company name. Once purchased you need to upload the digital cetitifcate then your website will display with your 'company name' like Mozilla.

Understanding Digital Certificates:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd361898.aspx

For your Ref:
What is a website digital certificate?

A digital certificate is a mechanism for users to obtain assurance about the identity and authenticity of a website. By inspecting the digital certificate on a website, users can help prevent identity theft and fraud. For example, a phishing site set up by criminals which masquerades as a legitimate website (such as an online banking web site) can often be identified by an invalid or absent digital certificate.