# what is the parts of an url like company name at the beginning ? and how can i add this kind of thing to my website?

Tags: web, https, ssl-certificate

[image]

i have seen many of commercial websites, have compromised their URL with company name as display above. i need this kind of thing to my web site too. can anybody advice me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Company name before website URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650479/company-name-before-website-url)

Answer (score 2):

This website is using [Extended Validation SSL certificate](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate) and the browser may or may not represent this in a special way to acknowledge for the higher security of this website.

In general, the EV certificate guarantee higher security, because the Certificate Authority that is issuing the certificate is responsible to verify that the purchaser of the certificate is the same as the legal owner of the domain + some additional info. And it is more expensive.

Answer (score 1):

This is an [Extended Validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate) SSL certificate.

They're much more expensive.

Answer (score 0):

That shows that a SSL certificate exsts for the website you are on. (SSL Encryption means that information that is passed between you and the website, like passwords, will be fairly well protected from spying by internet "hackers.")

You can google "free ssl certificate" and find providers that assist you in setting up a free SSL certificate. This is a good idea for various reasons and not that difficult to do.

Comment: The op's question refers to a special SSL certificate, not just some random free certificate.